# Table space dropped but dbf file still exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tablespace, data-files

we have dropped a tablespace by command drop tablespace T1 assuming that the datafile will also be dropped. Later we created the same tablespace T1 with different datafile.
Now the problem is that datafile is holding 14GB of diskspace. Is there any way to recover that space from the datafile. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/reclaiming-unused-space might help.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9004.htm

you needed to drop the datafile at the same time as dropping the tablespace

```
DROP TABLESPACE tablespace INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES CASCADE CONTRAINTS;
```

if you check DBA_DATA_FILES, if your old datafile is not listed you will be ok to remove it from the OS